# QGraphicsLineItem follows QGraphicsEllipseItem

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

Is there any way that a `QGraphicsLineItem` follows two `QGraphicsEllipseItems` in the sense that the starting point of the line is the position of the first `QGraphicsEllipseItem` end, and the end point is the position of the second `QGraphicsEllipseItem`. I tried to set one ellipse as parent, but the problem is, that there is only one parent for each Item. So I can get it to follow one of the points, but not the second one.

Comment: You'll have to outline what you're doing in more detail.  For instance, why couldn't the line the parent of the Ellipses?  ([see this recent Q&A for a possibly related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745025/))  A parent-child relationship isn't the only way to make things move together, just a convenient one if it fits.  You could avoid parent-child relationships altogether, watch the move notifications, and adjust whatever you liked in response.  *Notice you can edit your question to add more detail with the EDIT button...*

Comment: This was just an example of what I already tried, I just want the line to follow the points when they move and that was what I thought would work

Comment: Try looking at the [elastic nodes sample](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/graphicsview-elasticnodes.html) and see if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by implementing the mousePressEvent and mouseMoveEvent in a subclass of the QGraphicsScene and having a variable that stores the current selected node. Something along these lines:

```
# Allows moving nodes across the scene updating the connections
def mouseLeftClickMoveEvent(self,event):
    # If no node is selected, skip
    if self.selected_item is None:
        return

    # QtConnections are not movable
    if isinstance( self.selected_item, QtConnection ):
        return

    # Update the position of the selected node
    new_pos = event.scenePos()
    new_x = int(new_pos.x()/self.grid_size)*self.grid_size
    new_y = int(new_pos.y()/self.grid_size)*self.grid_size
    self.selected_item.setRect( QRectF(new_x,new_y,self.selected_item.node_size,self.selected_item.node_size) )

    # Update the position of the connections to the node
    for c in self.selected_item.incons:
        x1 = c.line().p1().x()
        y1 = c.line().p1().y()
        x2 = self.selected_item.rect().center().x()
        y2 = self.selected_item.rect().center().y()
        c.setLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)

    # Update the position of the connections from the node
    for c in self.selected_item.outcons:
        x1 = self.selected_item.rect().center().x()
        y1 = self.selected_item.rect().center().y()
        x2 = c.line().p2().x()
        y2 = c.line().p2().y()
        c.setLine(x1,y1,x2,y2)

    # Update the scene to repaint the background
    self.update()
```

For this to work, you will also have to subclass the QGraphicsEllipseItem so that you have an array with the incoming and outgoing connections. Something like:

```
class QtNode(QGraphicsEllipseItem):

   def __init__(self, node, layout):
       super(QGraphicsEllipseItem, self).__init__()
       self.id = node.id
       self.node = node
       self.incons  = []
       self.outcons = []
```

Also, a better solution might be to implement the mousePressEvent and mouseMoveEvent for the items themselves